# How do I login to Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I just set up Ubuntu Core on my Raspberry Pi 2 and it is now asking for a user name and password in the terminal.

The documentation says user name is:

ssh (Ubuntu SSO user name)@(device IP address)

But what about password?Is there a default one?

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [getting started guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3):

> During setup,console-conf will download the SSH key registered with your Store account and configure it so you can log into the device via ssh @ without a password.

[SSH](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) is a remote login, not a local one.

The idea is, instead of shipping with a default user and password (which owners often never change as proved by [marai](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirai_(malware))), in order to administer Ubuntu Core the only way in is via SSH authenticated by a cryptographic key pair, the public side of which you upload to your SSO account. Then, that initial wizard you went through asks for your SSO email, and uses it to download that key, allowing you to use the private key to login.

As mentioned on that page, instructions for generating this key can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys).

Once you gain access, if you wish, you can set a password thereby permitting local login.

Comment: I generated the SSH key and registered it.Then host login page came and I stuck in this stage.I tried entering without password but it is incorrect.

Comment: You cannot login locally. It must be done remotely via SSH.

Comment: Well,I generated and registered the SSH ,but I really don't understand what to do next.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I created the SSH key in Ubuntu 14.04 .

Comment: Then from that machine, open a terminal and type `ssh <SSO username>@<device IP address>` and, assuming the key was generated correctly, it'll use it to authenticate.